# Is there a way to leave the exception unhandled after invoking the VectorExceptionHandler the first time?

Tags: c++, seh

I want to check if a SEH occurred and if it's of a certain type I don't want to handle it and let the program crash, as it is important for having it generate a dump file. One issue is that my program has a VectorExceptionHandler in main but there are multiple threads being checked in the handler after some intervals and so after a considerate amount of time it crashes (when it reaches the thread with SEH). Is there a way to check and let it crash the first time it invokes the handler?